# Can SE sites have the code analysis in its scope?

Tags: discussion, area-51, scope

I'm asking if the SE sites or new proposals could have code analysis in its scope similar to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), or it's against Stack Exchange rules?

One example of question is [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/86094/11825), which was closed as off-topic (code analysis), therefore I've created the new [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86353/hackoverflow) (similar to [Code understanding](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding)) where (malicious) code analysis is on-topic and defining exactly what kind of code it's expected to be analysed.

Is that perfectly fine, fine, worth to try or code analysis is not suitable on SE sites at all?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/where-to-ask-for-code-explanation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192614/what-should-we-do-with-questions-that-ask-explain-this-code